# Embedded YouTube iframe working incorrectly in Safari (MacOS)

Tags: macos, iframe, youtube, safari, embed

I have a responsive embedded YouTube video on my (bootstrap) website.
When I choose the YouTube full screen option, it works on Firefox and Chrome, but on Safari it briefly flickers, then just shows the top of my entire web page in full screen, as though Safari itself is in full screen mode.

CSS:

```
.embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%; } .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class='embed-container'><iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/myyoutubecode?rel=0' frameborder='0' webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Does anyone know of a way to make this work in Safari?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.. in case anyone else experiences this:
wow.js animations seem to break the fullscreen functionality by causing this issue.  Disabling the animation for the div fixes the problem.

Comment: Spent a few hours, found this, and saved an additional few hours.  Thank you!  Note: remove the loading animation only on the container(s)/div(s)/section(s) that hold the embedded videos (not the entire page), AND THEN be sure to clear your caching software before testing.  Worked great for me!